# Cannot get file uploaded from react js frontend to express backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

```
//This is frontend


import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [logFile, setLogFile] = useState<File | null>(null);

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setLogFile(e.target.files![0]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("logFile", logFile!);
      console.log(formData);
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3001/logs",
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Upload file</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;






//This is backend
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;
const winston = require('winston');
const cors = require("cors")

app.use(cors())


const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      level: 'error',
      filename: 'error.log',
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: true,
      maxsize: 5242880,
      maxFiles: 5,
      colorize: false
    }),
    new winston.transports.File({
      level: 'warn',
      filename: 'warning.log',
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: true,
      maxsize: 5242880,
      maxFiles: 5,
      colorize: false
    })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});

app.use(express.json());


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ "message": req.body.logFile })
})


app.post('/logs', (req, res) => {
  const logFile = req.body.logFile;
  const errorLogs = [];
  const warnLogs = [];

  // Log error and warn messages to separate files
  logFile?.forEach(log => {
    if (log.level === 'error') {
      logger.error(log);
      errorLogs.push(log);
    } else if (log.level === 'warn') {
      logger.warn(log);
      warnLogs.push(log);
    }
  });

  res.json({ errorLogs, warnLogs });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I'm building a log parser to log error and warn levels using react js to upload file and return filtered data as json from express server. But I'm getting empty object for formData  but logfile is showing uploaded fie in console in my react js frontend

I want to send a log file from frontend to backend and return filtered json data from backend to frontend

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your code is that the form element doesn't have an onSubmit event, so the form is never submitted. To fix this, you can wrap your input element and submit button in a form element and add an onSubmit event that calls the `handleSubmit` function.

Another issue is that you're using the `fetch` API to make the POST request, which may not work correctly with a `multipart/form-data` content type. You can use the Axios library instead, which makes it easier to send binary data in the request body.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [logFile, setLogFile] = useState<File | null>(null);

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setLogFile(e.target.files![0]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("logFile", logFile!);

      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/logs", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Upload file</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Edit:**

The problem is that you are using `req.body.logFile` to access the uploaded file, but the file is being sent as a `multipart/form-data` request, not as a JSON request. You need to use a middleware that can handle `multipart/form-data` requests and extract the file.

To handle `multipart/form-data` requests in an Express application, you can use the `multer` middleware. Here is an example of how you can use it to extract the file from the request:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post('/logs', upload.single('logFile'), (req, res) => {
  const logFile = req.file;
  ...
});
```

In this example, the `upload.single('logFile')` will extract the file from the `logFile` field of the `multipart/form-data` request and store it in memory as a `Buffer`. You can then access the file using `req.file`

Comment: It is still giving me empty object

Comment: console.log(formData.get("logFile")); This console.log is returning file but when I console log formdata then it return empty objecct. I'm sending test.log file to the backend

Comment: I've added the backend code also if there is any issue with the backend please let me know